# How to tell if the wheel event happens over an element with a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this vue template, with a number of child components, many of which use `overflow-y` to show a scrollbar when they get too much content.

```
<div @wheel="onWheel">
...
</div>
```

And the corresponding handler is:

```
onWheel: function (ev) {
  //console.log(ev)
  if (event.deltaY < 0) this.goto(-1)
  else if (event.deltaY > 0) this.goto(+1)
},
```

I.e. the desired behaviour is for the mouse wheel to move up or down a database record, unless *it has something more obvious to do*. By that I mean, if it is over a component with a scroll bar, the user will expect the mouse wheel to scroll within that component, and not change the database record!

Is there a way to do this? I tried adding `.self`:

```
<div @wheel.self="onWheel">
...
</div>
```

But that stopped it working completely.

I wondered about trying to intercept the wheel event in each child component, but (apart from that being a maintenance nightmare) I am not sure this is possible as it is a special one ([at least in Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312)) that you cannot call `preventDefault()` on.

I can see from looking at `ev` that I know what element the mouse is over from `ev.target`. Could I somehow go from that to finding out if it, or any parent, is showing a scrollbar?

Comment: you can look to see if the element's scrollHeight != offsetHeight. you would also want to crawl up a chain of element.parentElement until you ran into something before <body>, and check those as above. you should be able to use one handler to cover the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not so much that you want to `preventDefault` as you want the event to not bubble up to the `parent` if the child component has its own defined `wheel` event. You can do this using:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

---

### Code Sandbox:

I created a codesandbox demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wheel-propagation-demo-cocnx

*Be sure to open the **console** in the **demo** to see the different events **fire***.

---

### Code Example:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div @wheel="onWheel" id="app">
    <img width="25%" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <Base msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!">this is a test</Base>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Base from "./components/Base";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Base
  },
  methods: {
    onWheel: function(e) {
      console.log("wheeling over " + e.currentTarget.id);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Base.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello" style="margin-top: 30px; padding: 30px; background: beige;">
    <slot></slot>
    <Wheeler>wheel me!</Wheeler>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Wheeler from "./Wheeler.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Wheeler
  },

  name: "Base",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>
```

**Wheeler.vue**

```
<template>
  <div @wheel="otherWheel" class="wheelMe">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    otherWheel: function(e) {
      console.log("wheeling over " + e.currentTarget.className);
      e.currentTarget.style["background-color"] =
        "rgb(" +
        [
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 254),
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 254),
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 254)
        ].toString() +
        ")";
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

### Note:

If you want to stop the wheel from causing a vertical `scroll` to occur you would handle that event separately.